# Email Messages UID in Java Mail API

Tags: jakarta-mail

Is there any way to get the an array of unique id for the messages stored in the in box folder of a mail account through Java language ?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on exactly what you mean by "unique id".

There's the [UIDFolder](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/UIDFolder.html) interface, which provides access to IMAP UIDs.  But you need to understand the semantics of IMAP UIDs to understand just how "unique" they are, and aren't.

There's also the [Message-ID](https://javamail.java.net/nonav/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeMessage.html#getMessageID--) header that appears on most messages.  While it's typically more globally unique than IMAP UIDs, there's no guarantee of uniqueness.

What do you want to do with the unique id once you have it?